# AngularJS - Pass Optional Parameter to Modal

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How do I pass an OPTIONAL parameter to my angularJS modal?  Here is my code:

CONTROLLER A (TRIGGER):

```
$modal.open({
  templateUrl: 'UploadPartial.html',
  controller: 'photos.uploadCtrl',
  resolve: {
    preselectedAlbum: function preselectedAlbum() {
      return angular.copy($scope.selectedAlbum);
    }
  }
});
```

CONTROLLER B (MODAL):

```
app.controller('photos.uploadCtrl', [
  '$scope',
  '$modalInstance',
  '$injector',
  function uploadCtrl($scope, $modalInstance, $injector) {
    if ($injector.has('preselectedAlbum')) {
      console.log('happy');  // I want this to work, but $injector doesn't find it
    } else {
      console.log('sad');  //  Always gets here instead :(
    }
  }
]);
```

NOTE: It works when i put `preselectedAlbum` as a dependency, but then i get the error whenever I don't explicitly pass it in.  I want it to be optional instead.

Comment: I don't think this is possible, the injected `$injector` service doesn't know anything about the `resolve:` object. You probably have to pass a dummy function when it is not required. Or change a way to pass the `preselectedAlbum`, may be via `$scope` object.

Comment: @runTarm can you please show how to pass information to a controller via the $scope object?  That would work perfectly for me if it is possible, but i don't know how to make changes to it that would persist in the new controller that's being opened.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Attach a value to the modal controller

```
angular.module('app')
    .controller('TestCtrl',TestCtrl)
    .value('noteId', null); // optional param
```

Comment: How did this get voted the correct answer? When opening a modal, you don't define it using the above fluent-type syntax. The controller is simply an attribute in the options passed to $modal.open(); i.e. you don't call module.controller() so .value is not available. I guess if the controller is registered as a part of of your module then you may be able to use .controller(...).value, but I doubt you have the value you want laying around at that point.

Answer (score 5):

Other than the `resolve:`, you could also pass values to the modal controller via `scope:`.

```
$scope.preselectedAlbum = angular.copy($scope.selectedAlbum);

$modal.open({
  templateUrl: 'UploadPartial.html',
  controller: 'photos.uploadCtrl',
  scope: $scope,
});
```

and then in the modal controller:

```
function uploadCtrl($scope, $modalInstance) {
  if ($scope.preselectedAlbum) {
    console.log('happy');
  } else {
    console.log('sad');
  }
}
```

**Example plunker:** http://plnkr.co/edit/ewbZa3I6xcrRWncPvDIi?p=preview